# Python in Vim buffer?

Tags: python, vim

Is it possible to have a Python interpreter open in a Vim buffer?  Something like:

```
________________________
|                      |
|                      |
|  my python script    |
|                      |
|                      |
------------------------
|                      |
|  python interpreter  |
------------------------
```

Right now I have Vim open and a separate interpreter open.  I saw the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501585/how-can-you-use-python-in-vim) and was blown away.

Anyway, thanks for the help and if there is something I can just google then point me in that direction.

Comment: how would you like to use it?

Comment: stefanB, I'd like to be able to switch between buffers without having to grab my mouse :)

Comment: @Casey - does you operating system support alt-tab application switching? I can switch between all my applications without using my mouse. ;)

Comment: Thrope, yeah i can alt-tab but was hoping for something in vim.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't run a shell in Vim by default. That's by design.

However, there are a handful of ways to accomplish this:

- [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and using windows
- [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and using windows
- The [Vim-Shell](http://www.wana.at/vimshell/) patch
- Vim scripts like [Conque](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771)

Comment: +1 for Screen, I find that combination excellent.

Comment: re GNU Screen: there's also BSD tmux

Comment: Yes tmux is a lot more intuitive when it comes to splitting the window.
https://wave.googleusercontent.com/wave/attachment/tmux_screenshot.png?id=RKdNEMeT2&key=AH0qf5w3fizXySmmU1s9jBAbPOMVK3lRHg

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at [PIDA](http://pida.co.uk/). Not exactly what you asked for but it is a Python IDE that embeds vim so might do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing me to PIDA. It looks awesome and works great on my machine (its like a dream come true). Do you know if there are any windows IDEs that can embed VIM?

Comment: Only other one I know is eclim which I think works on windows... haven't used it but it looks pretty flexible (you can have vim in eclipse basically)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Pimp](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2495).  Also, read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501585/how-can-you-use-python-in-vim).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this vim plugin seems to do the job.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2043

Answer (score 0):

what you want is have a vim window act as a terminal.  AFAIK vim can't do this (yet?).  otoh, if you aren't wed to vim (yet), try emacs, which does have that feature.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with tmux and [tslime.vim](https://github.com/kikijump/tslime.vim).

See this post for more info: http://joshuadavey.com/post/15619414829/faster-tdd-feedback-with-tmux-tslime-vim-and