# Run visual selection in external shell, send output to new window

Tags: python, vim

So I mainly use Vim for work in python at the moment, and I've recently discovered 2 great strategies for running code externally and bringing it back into Vim. The first is the use of a function called `Shell` from the [Vim pages](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window):

```
function! s:ExecuteInShell(command)
  let command = join(map(split(a:command), 'expand(v:val)'))
  let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . command . '$')
  silent! execute  winnr < 0 ? 'botright new ' . fnameescape(command) : winnr . 'wincmd w'
  setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap number
  echo 'Execute ' . command . '...'
  silent! execute 'silent %!'. command
  silent! execute 'resize ' . line('$')
  silent! redraw
  silent! execute 'au BufUnload <buffer> execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr('#') . ') . ''wincmd w'''
  silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>r :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . command . ''')<CR>'
  echo 'Shell command ' . command . ' executed.'
endfunction
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:ExecuteInShell(<q-args>)
```

which allows one to run something like `:Shell nosetests` and see the results in a new window that is:

1. Persistent (no "hit enter" to make it go away)
2. Uses a temporary buffer (not a temp file)
3. And most importantly, running the command again just refreshes the current window, it doesn't open a new one every time.

Then I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501585/how-can-you-use-python-in-vim) little gem as well:

```
:'<,'>:w !python
```

which let's me use a selection from my current buffer, but which goes away after hitting enter.

What I can't figure out how to do is combine the two. What I want is:

1. All the window properties of the `Shell` command, but
2. The ability to run it from a selection on the screen.
3. **EDIT: do this for selected python code, not bash code. The function already does regular shell commands. Instead of using Shell to run `$ python script.py` I want it to run code directly like `:'<,'>:w !python` would.**

I don't know enough Vimscript to modify `Shell` to include a selection, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to at least put `:'<,'>:w !python` into it's own window without the use of a temporary file, which seems unnecessary to me. Any ideas? Tips?

Comment: i don't know vimscript nearly well enough to fix this either, but since this code already uses `%!` from within the temp buffer, it'll probably work if you can get your selection copied into the temp buffer first.  maybe user-defined commands can accept ranges?  good luck  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the function accept ranges and test if a range was passed by:

```
function! s:ExecuteInShell(command) range
  let lines = []
  if (a:firstline != a:lastline)
    let lines=getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
  endif
  let command = join(map(split(a:command), 'expand(v:val)'))
  let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . command . '$')
  silent! execute  winnr < 0 ? 'botright new ' . fnameescape(command) : winnr . 'wincmd w'
  setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap number
  echo 'Execute ' . command . '...'
  if (len(lines))
    silent! call append(line('.'), lines)
    silent! 1d
    silent! redir => results
    silent! execute '1,$w !' . command
    silent! redir end
    silent! %d
    let lines = split(results, '\r')
    for line in lines[:1]
        call append(line('$'), line[1:])
    endfor
    silent! 1d
  else
    silent! execute 'silent %!'. command
  endif
  silent! execute 'resize ' . line('$')
  silent! redraw
  silent! execute 'au BufUnload <buffer> execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr('#') . ') . ''wincmd w'''
  silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>r :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . command . ''')<CR>'
  echo 'Shell command ' . command . ' executed.'
endfunction
command! -range -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell <line1>,<line2>call s:ExecuteInShell(<q-args>)
```

To use with a command:

```
:Shell echo 'no range supplied, but a command (echo) is.'
```

To use while lines are selected (you don't type the "'<,'>" part as press ":" will put that there for you (command supplied as the lines selected are interpreted by the command):

```
:'<,'>Shell python
```

Comment: Using that code verbatim, a new window pops up but nothing gets run. I typed `ls -hal` in an empty buffer, then I visually selected the line and ran it like: `:Shell '<,'>`. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: Two things.  First, this script needs more than one line passed in as the only way I found to determine if a range was selected was by a:firstline being different than a:lastline.  Second, this script needs to be passed a command to use (i.e. python).  You might be able to edit it to use the lack of a command passed to know that the lines are things to run.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version that uses lack of a command to process a range of lines:

```
function! s:ExecuteInShell(command) range
  let lines = []
  if (!len(a:command))
    let lines=getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
  endif
  let command = join(map(split(a:command), 'expand(v:val)'))
  let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . command . '$')
  silent! execute  winnr < 0 ? 'botright new ' . fnameescape(command) : winnr . 'wincmd w'
  setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap number
  echo 'Execute ' . command . '...'
  if (len(lines))
    for line in lines
        silent! execute 'silent r! '. line
    endfor
    silent! 1d
  else
    silent! execute 'silent %!'. command
  endif
  silent! execute 'resize ' . line('$')
  silent! redraw
  silent! execute 'au BufUnload <buffer> execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr('#') . ') . ''wincmd w'''
  silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>r :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . command . ''')<CR>'
  echo 'Shell command ' . command . ' executed.'
endfunction
command! -range -complete=shellcmd -nargs=* Shell <line1>,<line2>call s:ExecuteInShell(<q-args>)
```

To use with a command:

```
:Shell echo 'no range supplied, but a command (echo) is.'
```

To use while lines are selected (you don't type the "'<,'>" part as press ":" will put that there for you (no command supplied as the lines selected supply the command):

```
:'<,'>Shell
```

Comment: this is great, thanks! The other half of the question though was how to do this for running python code as well. I wasn't clear in my original questions so I'll update it now. I tried some things myself thinking it was trivial, but simply adding `python` before/after the `!` didn't work as I thought it would. Is that an addition you think you could make @cforbish ?

Comment: This is what I understood with my original answer.  I have updated my original answer with details on how to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying `:'<,'>Shell python` with the script in this answer returns an empty window.