# Running python/bash code in Rstudio

Tags: python, r, bash, rstudio

I am using Rstudio for my day to day R stuff. Sometimes, I'd like to use some python/bash for the parts that R isn't super good at. Curiously enough I've noticed if I start an new RMarkdown document, that the following code works:

````
```{r engine='python'}
print "Hello" + "World"
import random
print random.random()
```
````

[image: python in rstudio]

Rstudio can run me some python. This is very useful, but preferably I would be able to run this not just via the markdown feature but through a console as well. In the [release notes](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/release-notes/) it is suggested that there is support for syntax highlighting.

I wonder, is there any method to connect a new console to Rstudio such that we could also do some python/bash from the IDE? It certainly seems like Rstudio has a notion of how to connect to python. The end goal would be to create `.Rmd` documents and be able to edit/interact with them that have the following structure:

````
# Use Case 

Connect to an api that is supported in python

```{r engine='python', highlight=TRUE}
data = foobar_api.get(1000)
file_loc = open("~/data/filename.csv", "w")
file_loc(data) 
file_loc.close()
```

Then analyse with R again. 

```{r}
df <- read.csv("~/data/filename.csv")
summary(df)
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to set the `knitr` options.

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine.path = list(python = '/anaconda/bin/python'))
```
````

From that point on it just works.

````
```{python}
import this 
```
````

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Architect](http://www.openanalytics.eu/architect) or plain [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) with [StatET](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet), you can install the [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org) plug-ins and launch and interact with Python consoles as easily as you would do with your R Consoles (and, there is, of course, ample support for editing and processing .Rmd files)

Comment: is it from the same file?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of knitr at it's best, where it allows for [multiple language engines](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/). You might consider editing the file for just these cases in VIM, because you can do something fun that is close to what you are asking: select the text and then type:

```
:'<,'>!python
```

to execute in python and

```
:<','>!R --no-save
```

To execute in R. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501585/how-can-you-use-python-in-vim) for more details.

The above does not solve the use case completely, because the selected text is replaced by the output of the command (starting with the R version etc. in the case of a simple R command). It is possible however, to send the output to a different buffer (read: window) using [this vimtip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window).

The VIM-mode in RStudio is nothing short of excelent (it even supports visual block mode). But it cannot emulate everything and `:!python` in RStudio will not work. I often have the document I'm working on open in both RStudio and VIM, and the above might be a reason for you to do the same for Rmd documents with mixed languages.